# Verb + ようなんて, what does that do?

Tags: grammar

I'm watching Ponyo, this is dialogue at 30:15:

> お前達に農場の仕事を見せようなんて連れて来たのがいけなかったのだ。

I'm not sure about ようなんて, what does that do grammatically? Anyway here's how I understand it:

> It was not possible to bring you guys to watch farm work.

But the English version of the movie has:

> Bringing you along to watch me was a mistake.

Is the English version just taking liberties or am I wrong in my interpretation?

Comment: Your question is more about いけない than なんて. He already bring them see him because of 来た (past tense).

Comment: It was not good idea to have brought you guys to show the farm work. Does it match the scene?

Answer (score 0):

"[よう](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%82%88%E3%81%86-652682#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88)" in this case is an auxilliary verb, indicating will/intent for something, in 終止形{しゅうしけい}-form　(more commonly known as dictionary form). The adverbial particle "[なんて](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A6-590615#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)" is attached to verbs in that form, and it essentially means "などという" in Japanese. 
It's basically a way of bringing up actions such as that in a disparaging way, "something like x".

The real problem, as people in the comments mentioned, is actually [いける](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B-202380#E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.9E.97.20.E7.AC.AC.E4.B8.89.E7.89.88) ("物事をうまくすることができる。うまくこなす", "To be able to do something well"). 
Since the speaker is explaining (のだ) that having brought them along to show them how it is to work on a farm did not go well, that was was translated as "bringing you here was a bad idea".